# Questions about CTS/VTS and CDD for android 10

Tags: cts, automotive

We are developing Head Unit for Automotive and using Android 10.
We won't integrate Google Play Services on this. I concern that we have to run and pass CTS/VTS or not? And, Do you have compliant all items in Android CDD?

Please help us to make clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, you are not Integrating the GMS Package, which would be the case like OEMs - Zebra, who launches their product without GMS suite, in this case, you can avoid testing and certification for GTS but if you claim, your phone is android then you have to pass CTS, CTS on GSI, STS, VTS, CTS Verifier compulsory.